# Static parameter Web Intelligence BO

Tags: business-objects

I'm new to BO here and was wondering if there is a way to put in a static parameter in a Business Objects report. For instance, in SQL reporting, you can type in static values for a parameter that you can then pass to the query. Is there something similar in BO? I would imagine so.

Answer (score -2):

In BO

By Default It Will De Static Values 
U can create the Dynamic Instances For The report so each And every Time When u Refresh The page u can dynamically allot The vales to the instance

Comment: Please improve spelling, marking as low quality post